# invalid pattern in a XML schema

Tags: xml, schema

I have a pattern in a XML Schema. It is:

```
<xs:pattern value="^[^\u00A4\u00A6\u007C\u00A7\u0022]+$"/>.
```

But when the schema is opened via Altova, we get the error

> The schema doesn't appear to be valid by itself(as part of another schema it might still be ok)...Value `^[^\u00A4\u00A6\u007C\u00A7\u0022]+$` is not a regular xml expression

I can't see anything wrong with the expression. Can anyone help me identify the problem?

Comment: sorry, here is the actual pattern from the schema:  <xs:pattern value="^[^\u00A4\u00A6\u007C\u00A7\u0022]+$"/>

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix here, update from Javascript to XML form for the character references:

```
<xs:pattern value="^[^&#x00A4;&#x00A6;&#x007C;&#x00A7;&#x0022;]+$"/>
```

-------------EDIT--------------------

Thanks to Michael Kay for pointing out the anchoring oversight. If you want to prohibit the use of the characters ¤¦|" then this is your pattern:

```
<xs:pattern value="[^&#x00A4;&#x00A6;&#x007C;&#x00A7;&#x0022;]+"/>
```

From the spec:

```
Note:  Unlike some popular regular expression languages (including those defined by Perl and standard Unix utilities), the regular expression language defined here implicitly anchors all regular expressions at the head and tail, as the most common use of regular expressions in ·pattern· is to match entire literals.
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs

Comment: That's now a valid XSD regex, but not the one intended, since in the XSD regex dialect "^" and "$" are ordinary characters, not metacharacters. You can just leave them out in this case, since the XSD pattern facet is implicitly anchored to the start and end of the string.